# Norm inequalities on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I just ran through this simple, but not so simple problem, and I want to share it.

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$, I can always find the constant c so that the 1 norm $\|x\|_1$ is less than or equal to the product of that constant c and the Euclidian norm $\|x\|_2$

$$\|x\|_1 \leq c\|x\|_2$$

It turns out that that constant is $\sqrt{n}$. I tried it on a couple of basic cases on  $\mathbb{R}^3$, and  $\mathbb{R}^2$, have a rather nice proof for  $\mathbb{R}^2$ just by using algebra 2.

My question is, can we also prove this for the general case  $\mathbb{R}^n$, or just bigger case such as  $\mathbb{R}^5$ for example?

Thanks for any positive discussion.

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: Is that the one that says the abs value of the dot product is less than or equal to the product of the norm?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: I do not understand what are you asking for. "It turns out that" you already know that the statement is true, except that you misstated it: You need to allow a Euclidean norm, not necessarily the standard one. Google "Banach-Mazur distance".

Comment: I actually did not know that it is $\sqrt{n}$, i checked every case, I was actually amazed. Everything has its first time, you know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we obtain

$$\lVert x \rVert_1 = \sum_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k\rvert = \sum_{k=1}^n 1\cdot \lvert x_k\rvert \leqslant \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n 1^2} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \lvert x_k\rvert^2} = \sqrt{n}\lVert x\rVert_2.$$

Taking the point with all coordinates $1$ shows that the bound is sharp.

Comment: I'm sorry, but im still new at this. What do you mean by the bound is sharp?

Comment: That means it's the best bound possible. For every smaller $C$, there are $x$ with $\lVert x\rVert_1 > C\cdot \lVert x\rVert_2$. In fact, here, we have $x \neq 0$ with $\lVert x\rVert_1 = \sqrt{n}\lVert x\rVert_2$.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a less trivial theorem: One says that the distance between two (arbitrary) norms $|x|_1$ and $|x|_2$ on ${\mathbb R}^n$ is $\le C$ if 
$$
C^{-1}|x|_1\le |x|_2 \le C |x|_1, \forall x\in {\mathbb R}^n. 
$$
One says that a norm on ${\mathbb R}^n$ is *Euclidean* if it is defined via a positive-definite quadratic form.

Theorem. Every norm on ${\mathbb R}^n$ is within distance $\le \sqrt{n}$ from a Euclidean norm.